# Draw a circle with fan blades inside, Java

Tags: java

I have to display four "fans" or arcs that are outlined by a circle, i have the fanblades/arcs set and looking the way i would like but i cannot figure out how to get them outlined by a circle, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
package chap15;


import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Fans extends JPanel {


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);



    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

    int x = xCenter - radius;
    int y = yCenter - radius;

    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 0, 30);
    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 90, 30);
    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 180, 30);
    g.fillArc(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius, 270, 30);

}
}
```

Comment: You seem to have found `fillArc`, how about `drawArc`?

Comment: Thank you as the light bulb goes on in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[drawArc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)?